# How to print a string at the end of line using awk?

Tags: awk

I am very new to awk. I am trying to add a new calculated column. But awk insert the column to the next line rather to the end of the current line.

Here is an example of my data:

```
,2013-11-22,12.9,26.0,26.6,,,NW
```

What I am trying to do is to add a column at the end containing YES, or NO based on the fifth column (if $5 > 0 YES else NO).

Here is my awk command:

```
awk -F, '{
    if($5 > 0) print $0, ",YES"; else print $0, ",NO"
}' data.csv
```

The result is something like this:

```
,2013-11-22,12.9,26.0,26.6,,,NW
YES
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `print `...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign straight into fields in `awk` with `$N`, for `N` the field number: `$9 = "YES"` will add a new field at the end with the value `"YES"`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ if ($5 > 5) { $9 = "YES" } else {$9 = "NO"} };1' data
```

When we assign into `$9` we create the ninth field, which is one beyond the end for this data. Putting `1` at the end forces `awk`'s default output to occur, which we'd have suppressed otherwise.

For your sample the above gives you:

```
,2013-11-22,12.9,26.0,26.6,,,NW,YES
```

which I think is what you wanted.

If you want it to be the last field, regardless of how many fields there were to start with, we can use the number of fields `NF`, making sure we go one beyond it:

```
awk -v OFS=, -F, '{ if ($5 > 5) {$(NF+1)="YES"} else {$(NF+1)="NO"} };1' data
```

`$` accepts any numeric expression, so we can add one to `NF` to get access to the next available field.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Is there shortcut that refer to last field? I am thinking maybe the number of column will change in the future. The shortcut will help the script to not break in case this occurs.

Comment: I just tested the code and I still have the same problem. YES/NO will added but form the next line.

Comment: You can use `$(NF+1)` to access the last field always (see edit).

Comment: Not with the data you provided and the command I gave it won't. It just uses `awk`'s default (single-line) output separated by `OFS`.

Comment: I realized what the problem was. In my file I had ^M character at the end of line, which messed everything up. I have to get rid of ^M character, somehow

Answer (score 2):

A shorter `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F',' '$(NF+1) = $5 > 0 ? "YES" : "NO"' OFS=',' file
```

If your file contains `windows` newline character, you can remove it:

```
$ awk -F',' '{sub(/\r$/,"")} $(NF+1) = $5 > 0 ? "YES" : "NO"' OFS=',' file
```